# How to identify a bad disk in a RAID setup on Linux?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I am observing the below error on dmesg for a RAID Array. How can i go about finding which drive in the RAID is bad

```
[Fri Aug 26 19:31:13 2022] EXT4-fs warning (device md0): ext4_end_bio:349: I/O error 10 writing to inode 100728932 starting block 1514702321)
[Fri Aug 26 19:31:13 2022] buffer_io_error: 80 callbacks suppressed
[Fri Aug 26 19:31:13 2022] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 1514702124
[Fri Aug 26 19:31:13 2022] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 1514702125
```

I also happen to do a health check with smartctl on all the disks that are part of RAID, All turned out ***OK*** so i was thinking that i could just re-seat the disks once and that should work but i wanted a longer term solution in identifying the underlying bad disk or any command that could help me verify what is triggering the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to check on my RAID since I have had issues on my RAID.  Turns out that I needed locking SATA cables as they were coming loose causing my drives to look like they were erroring out.

Anyways, here is my script that I run, and an example below of it in action:

**The Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check for root
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Please run $0 as root"
  echo ""
  echo "example:"
  echo "sudo $0"
  exit 1
fi

# Check for smartmontools
smartctl -h > /dev/null
case $? in
    1) echo "smartmontools is not installed.  Please install it with the following command:"
    echo ""
    echo "sudo apt install smartmontools"
    exit 1;;
    0) ;;
esac

awk '/: active/ {print $1}' /proc/mdstat | while read drv
do
    sudo mdadm -D /dev/$drv
done

echo ""

# Create drive array
drives=( $(smartctl --scan | awk '{print $1}') )

# Loop through array and check each drive
for ((i=0; i < ${#drives[@]}; ++i))
do
    model=$(smartctl -a ${drives[$i]} | grep -i "device model:" | awk '{print substr($0,index($0,$3))}')
    serial=$(smartctl -a ${drives[$i]} | grep -i "serial number:" | awk '{print $NF}')
    result=$(smartctl -H ${drives[$i]} | awk '/overall-health/ {print $NF}')
    echo -n "${drives[$i]} Model: $model Serial: $serial SMART: $result"
    j=$(echo ${drives[$i]} | cut -d/ -f3); echo -n " Errors: "
    grep -i error /var/log/kern.log 2>/dev/null | grep "$j," | wc -l
done
```

**Example:**

```
terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo ./drive_check.bsh 
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Dec 27 18:06:03 2017
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 484323328 (461.89 GiB 495.95 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 484323328 (461.89 GiB 495.95 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Sep  1 08:12:59 2022
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : Intrepid:root  (local to host Intrepid)
              UUID : f9b257fc:d64f97c7:95581e88:004e3a4b
            Events : 71486

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       2       8      161        0      active sync   /dev/sdk1
       1       8        1        1      active sync   /dev/sda1
/dev/md2:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Dec 27 18:18:25 2017
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 3927040 (3.75 GiB 4.02 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 3927040 (3.75 GiB 4.02 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sun Aug  7 10:59:07 2022
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : Intrepid:swap  (local to host Intrepid)
              UUID : 2cdfcb03:e5e0c30f:d68d4e20:37b50e41
            Events : 191

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       2       8      165        0      active sync   /dev/sdk5
       1       8        5        1      active sync   /dev/sda5
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Feb  3 01:16:55 2015
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 15627542528 (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 3906885632 (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 5
     Total Devices : 5
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Sep  1 07:39:42 2022
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 5
   Working Devices : 5
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : Intrepid:1  (local to host Intrepid)
              UUID : 3bb988cb:d5270497:36e75f46:67a9bc65
            Events : 1155019

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       81        0      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       1       8       97        1      active sync   /dev/sdg1
       2       8      113        2      active sync   /dev/sdh1
       3       8      129        3      active sync   /dev/sdi1
       5       8      145        4      active sync   /dev/sdj1

/dev/sda Model: MAXTOR STM3500630A Serial: 9QG9152W SMART: PASSED Errors: 0
/dev/sdf Model: WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0 Serial: WD-WCC4EJPD3EXP SMART: PASSED Errors: 0
/dev/sdg Model: WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0 Serial: WD-WCC4E5UZUKPY SMART: PASSED Errors: 0
/dev/sdh Model: WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0 Serial: WD-WCC4E3XCP660 SMART: PASSED Errors: 0
/dev/sdi Model: WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0 Serial: WD-WCC4E7ZRRN8U SMART: PASSED Errors: 0
/dev/sdj Model: WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0 Serial: WD-WCC4EJXKY26C SMART: PASSED Errors: 0
/dev/sdk Model: ST3500418AS Serial: 6VM1HTNN SMART: PASSED Errors: 0
```

Comment: Thank you @Terrance :) I will try the script you have provided